# Viber installation problem

Tags: 14.04, viber

I tried to install Viber on my 32-bit Ubuntu 14.04 laptop. I installed wine and downloaded viber.exe file. Then I tried to install viber with wine, but the installation stops and outputs:

`One or more issues caused the installation to fail. Please fix the issues and try again.`

Then they have attached this log file :

```
----------


[0029:002A][2015-09-22T15:50:28]i001: Burn v3.9.1208.0, Windows v6.2 (Build 9200: Service Pack 0), path: Z:\home\poshan\ViberSetup.exe, cmdline: '-burn.unelevated BurnPipe.{7228FF2A-2A3C-4046-A2D5-7EE95BA1AFB3} {4AA84B10-3FFA-4C50-9459-81847BF37C0F} 38 '
[0029:002A][2015-09-22T15:50:28]i000: Initializing string variable 'InstallFolder' to value '[LocalAppDataFolder]\Viber\'
[0029:002A][2015-09-22T15:50:28]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\users\poshan\Temp\Viber_20150922155028.log'
[0029:002A][2015-09-22T15:50:28]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'Z:\home\poshan\ViberSetup.exe'
[0029:002A][2015-09-22T15:50:28]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder' to value 'Z:\home\poshan\'
[0029:002A][2015-09-22T15:50:28]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'Viber'
[0029:002F][2015-09-22T15:50:28]i000: Setting version variable 'WixBundleFileVersion' to value '5.3.0.1884'
[0029:002A][2015-09-22T15:50:28]i100: Detect begin, 1 packages
[0029:002A][2015-09-22T15:50:28]i101: Detected package: ViberSetup.msi, state: Absent, cached: None
[0029:002A][2015-09-22T15:50:28]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[0029:002F][2015-09-22T15:50:32]i000: Setting numeric variable 'EulaAcceptCheckbox' to value 1
[0029:002A][2015-09-22T15:50:32]i200: Plan begin, 1 packages, action: Install
[0029:002A][2015-09-22T15:50:32]i052: Condition 'VersionNT>=v6.1' evaluates to true.
[0029:002A][2015-09-22T15:50:32]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_ViberSetup.msi' to value 'C:\users\poshan\Temp\Viber_20150922155028_0_ViberSetup.msi_rollback.log'
[0029:002A][2015-09-22T15:50:32]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_ViberSetup.msi' to value 'C:\users\poshan\Temp\Viber_20150922155028_0_ViberSetup.msi.log'
[0029:002A][2015-09-22T15:50:32]i201: Planned package: ViberSetup.msi, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[0029:002A][2015-09-22T15:50:32]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[0029:002A][2015-09-22T15:50:32]i300: Apply begin
[0029:002A][2015-09-22T15:50:38]i000: Caching bundle from: 'C:\users\poshan\Temp\{e577cb09-2068-44fb-8eed-cfcc1617b010}\.be\ViberSetup.exe' to: 'C:\users\poshan\Local Settings\Application Data\Package Cache\{e577cb09-2068-44fb-8eed-cfcc1617b010}\ViberSetup.exe'
[0029:002A][2015-09-22T15:50:44]e000: Error 0x80070005: Failed to cache bundle from: 'C:\users\poshan\Temp\{e577cb09-2068-44fb-8eed-cfcc1617b010}\.be\ViberSetup.exe' to 'C:\users\poshan\Local Settings\Application Data\Package Cache\{e577cb09-2068-44fb-8eed-cfcc1617b010}\ViberSetup.exe'
[0029:002A][2015-09-22T15:50:44]e000: Error 0x80070005: Failed to cache bundle from path: C:\users\poshan\Temp\{e577cb09-2068-44fb-8eed-cfcc1617b010}\.be\ViberSetup.exe
[0029:002A][2015-09-22T15:50:44]e000: Error 0x80070005: Failed to begin registration session.
[0029:002A][2015-09-22T15:50:44]e000: Error 0x80070005: Failed to register bundle.
[0029:002A][2015-09-22T15:50:44]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80070005, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No


--------
```

What should i do?

Comment: Viber has an Ubuntu client. See here https://www.viber.com/en/products/linux

Comment: @Wildcard don't mind- I see only  for 64-bit not 32-bit

Comment: Is `wine ViberSetup.exe` the command you used to install wine after downloading

Comment: yes, i installed wine and downloaded viber and used the command wine ViberSetup.exe

Answer (score 2):

Viber has a Linux version. It is lot easier to install and use than using the Windows version through Wine.

---

To install Viber on Ubuntu open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run :

```
wget http://download.cdn.viber.com/cdn/desktop/Linux/viber.deb
dpkg -i viber.deb
```

Comment: does that work for 32-bit?

Comment: Right... I don't think so... Can you try ? I do not have a 32-bit system

Comment: i am trying, i'll let you know..

Comment: i downloaded the file but when i typed in the second command
it says this
dpkg: error: requested operation requires superuser privilege

Comment: `sudo dpkg --force-architecture -i viber.deb ` use this command inplace of second command, ....comment result

Comment: the command worked. then i typed in viber at the search, the app showed up. But, when i click on it, it does't load! nothing shows up!

Comment: If you type `viber` in a terminal, what happen ?

Comment: No command 'viber' found, did you mean:
 Command 'biber' from package 'biber' (universe)
 Command 'viper' from package 'python-viper' (universe)
viber: command not found

Comment: try `Viber` with a capital "v"